# What is the role of complevel argument in pandas to_hdf() function?

Tags: python, pandas, compression

I have been trying different values of the **complevel** argument of the pandas [DataFrame.to_hdf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html) function and it seems to have no influence in the resulting file, at least for  snappy compression in terms of final file size.

The pandas documentation doesn not really offer a great explanation on that argument:

> ```
> complevel{0-9}, optional: Specifies a compression level for data. A value of 0 disables compression.
> ```

This is the sample code I am running:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000, 100))

for i in range(10):
    filename = "test_data{}.sz".format(i)
    df.to_hdf(filename, key="data", complib="blosc:snappy", complevel=i)
    size = os.path.getsize(filename)
    print("Size for complevel {}: {}".format(i, size))
```

And this is the result I am obtaining:

```
Size for complevel 0: 80807312
Size for complevel 1: 80273721
Size for complevel 2: 80273721
Size for complevel 3: 80273721
Size for complevel 4: 80273721
Size for complevel 5: 80273721
Size for complevel 6: 80273721
Size for complevel 7: 80273721
Size for complevel 8: 80273721
Size for complevel 9: 80273721
```

As you can see, only for `complevel=0` (i.e. no compression) the size is slightly bigger. I would like to know why the behaviour of the compression doesn't change for the different possible levels.